# Zookeeper for High availability

Tags: apache-zookeeper, talend

How does zookeeper work in the following situation.

Consider I am having 3 (1,2,3) vm's and different services are running at their endpoints. My entire administration setup (TAC) is available only on the 1st vm (virtual machine) that means whenever a client wants to connect, it would by default connect to the first vm. My other 2  vm's they are just running bunch of services. This entire  cluster setup is maintained by the Zookeeper.

My question is what is the 1st vm fails. I know zookeeper maintains high availability by electing another vm as the master but client by default only points to 1st vm but not to other two. Is there any chance I can overcome this situation by getting the Ip of the first node as my admin setup is entirely present only on that node or in any other method?

Comment: don't understand why you can't provide the ips of the other two vms. how about setup hostnames or to use lvs ?

Comment: Hard to understand your question and the relation to ZooKeeper. At the end, you implement how clients connect to servers to access the services. ZooKeeper only maintains distributed states, e.g. to find available services.